# Mutants and Masterminds, Linked Actions and Reactions to gain Standard Actions

Tags: optimization, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Linked actions cannot be linked between ones with different action costs, this is pretty straightforward and clearly designed in order to prevent people like me getting extra actions per turn. Understandable, fair enough. However, Power Profiles clearly shows that I can trigger a reaction with my use of a move action, page 65

> Explosive Quantum Breakdown: Teleport, Burst Area Reaction Damage
>   (explosion, upon teleporting) • 2 points per Teleport rank + 5 points
>   per Damage rank

So since I can now take two standard actions per turn, can I take three instead by using Move by Action to teleport trigger reaction, action teleport trigger reaction?

This is doubly important because of cases like this

- Blink has reaction Teleport(Incoming attacks)

This would allow Blink to an additional attack whenever he's targeted. Reaction Teleport also has an example in Power profiles in page 204,

> Temporal Sidestep: Immunity 80 (Dodge and Parry based attacks), Concentration, >Limited (not against surprise attacks); Reaction Teleport 1 (when attacked) • >32 points + 5 points per additional rank of Reaction Teleport.

- Blink uses a teleport action to trigger a slam attack, he has a +15 to hit a +1 unarmed damage power and a teleport rank of +9.

Since the Slam damage is circumstantial he is now far over the Power Limit. And attacking multiple times per round. And don't talk to me about the recoil from Slam, obviously Blink is taking Immunity(Toughness Limited(Slam Recoil)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of your question, about [Slam](http://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-SLAM-ATTACK) damage, has a canonical answer.

> The Gamemaster may limit your base slam attack damage (before applying circumstance modifiers) by the series power level.
>
> *Example: Your hero flies into a foe, moving at speed rank 10. His unarmed damage (Strength) rank is only 2, so he uses his speed rank of 10 for the damage. Since he also moved his full speed to build up momentum, he increases his damage by +1 for a total damage rank of 11. If a base damage rank of 10 is too high for the series, the GM may impose a lower limit on his slam attack damage, applying the +1 modifier for the full speed move to the lowered rank.*

So, in short, there's nothing guaranteeing you a chance to break PL, especially if you have a character built to avoid any of the damage from doing the attack.

As regards [reaction](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers/#TOC-REACTION-1-OR-3-COST-PER-RANK-) "attacks" by linking it to movement, the onus is on the GM to police abusive builds like that.

> The GM is the final arbiter as to whether or not a triggering circumstance is suitable for a particular effect in the context of the series. Caution should be used to keep this option from being abused.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your initial question, you are mistaken to believe that your are gaining a second standard action in this way.

What you are doing is adding a damage effect to a move action.  Just because that move action requires people to make a save if they are close enough (by the way, as written you'll need to make the saves too) doesn't transform it into a standard action.

That said, you are approaching M&M in a way that is inappropriate.

Mutants and Masterminds is a game which has a very diverse set of Effects you can use to build powers, and those Effects can trivially be combined in ways that break the game (such as the famous 'bathroom mentalist' who can kill the entire Universe without leaving her home).  Building a game-breaking power isn't a challenge in M&M, it's fifteen minutes of effort.

Rather, the challenge is to build a character that has a consistent theme and style who will be fun to play.  Any GM I've ever played with would say "Nope" on that teleportation power unless it was made a full-round action.  They'd almost certainly be willing to allow you to build an Alternate Effect of it with a wide-area Damage effect though (representing multiple teleports in an area, to damage all enemies within it).

Comment: Instead I'm asking because I want to confirm if my understanding of the game is flawed and these are not actually as exploitative as I believe. This is why I have never had a thought out build in any of the questions I have posed. I'm asking about my thought experiments not anything I would consider playing, at worst these might end up being a big bad if I am to ever QM an adventure.

Comment: It occurs to me now I didn't actually address the question topic. Economy of action relies on some options being more powerful than others. If I can link reactions to my own actions then suddenly movement actions become almost as valuable as standard actions and god forbid I link it to a free action like making snappy one liners. True they are not as good as standard actions as they can only be used in a specific way, however in most cases I can assume that they are doing what I'd like them to do.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, to use move and free actions as standard actions, you can simply take the reaction modifier and then downgrade it with the increased action flaw. (Remember that you can only use one free action per effect only, so you can't have two attacks as free actions; you can only do it once per round.)

Also, if what you're looking for is additional actions, just get a sidekick/minions.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: If you could edit your answer to give it a less comment-like tone, it would be more appropriate to this site. Starting with "I mean", causes the readers to think you are elaborating on an already existing answer.